# VS Code: Open Files as Last Tab instead of Next to Current

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, when I open another file, or create a new one (ctrl+n), said file open next to the currently selected tab. **I would like this to behave the way browsers do.** Well, at least the way firefox/chrome do for me.

I find I am dragging tabs around a lot because my file look ups end up inserted between my order of other files. [image: This is the current behaviour.] I want it to instead always open the files as the last tab, the same way all my browsers do.

Ideally I would still like definitions to open in the next tab instead of the last, i.e., again, the way browsers do it.

I can't seem to find any settings for this, and I didn't find useful search results, just a bunch of stuff around not having the quick view tabs that get updated.

Comment: This should do the trick: `workbench.editor.openPositioning: last`

Comment: That's an improvement, but sadly causes definition lookups to be last as well. I can live with that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Aivar Paalberg, added as a comment.

> This should do the trick: workbench.editor.openPositioning: last